# How to format weekly date range in "calendar week text" to appear as 1 - 6, 7 - 13, 14 - 20, and so on?

Tags: pgfgantt

If I use something like this:

```
\ganttset{%
    calendar week text={%
        \small {\startday}
    }%
}
```

I can get the week to be broken down by date:

[image]

But I want it to show the date for both the start of the week and the end of the week. Something like this:

[image]

Thanks

EDIT: Here's an example of the code I am using:

```
\ganttset{%
    calendar week text={%
        \small {\startday}
    }%
}

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        x unit=2mm,
        time slot format=isodate,
        ]{2021-03-01}{2021-03-31}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name, week=1} \\
        \ganttbar{A}{2021-03-01}{2021-03-07} \\
        \ganttbar{B}{2021-03-08}{2021-03-14} \\
        \ganttbar{C}{2021-03-15}{2021-03-21} \\
        \ganttbar{D}{2021-03-22}{2021-03-28} \\
        \ganttbar{E}{2021-03-29}{2021-03-31} 
        ]
    \end{ganttchart}      
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Hi there, someone keeps deleting my comments. I have edited the post as requested.